# Having trouble creating a new array of objects in angular (loop inside of loop)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

What I am trying to do is compare the two arrays "similarBands" and "artistsArray". I want to take note of every match that occurs in the two arrays (that was my logic behind creating the counter). The end result that I am looking for is a new Array of objects (called newMatchingArray) all the matches of these two arrays, which will take a name property and a matches property (which indicates how many matches there were).

The function now correctly finds matches but doesn't increase the "counter" at every match, it stops at 2. I'm totally new to JS and AJAX so sorry for the obvious question/lacking of technical detail. Thanks!

```
  $scope.getBandsLikeThisBand = function(){
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'Get',
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + $scope.bandId + '/related-artists',
            success: function(data){
              console.log($scope.allTheArtists);
              $scope.similarBandsArray = data.artists;
              $scope.similarMathesArray = [];
              $scope.newMatchingArray = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.similarBandsArray.length; i ++){ //going through every related artist from the search
                  var counter = 0;
                  for (var x = 0; x < $scope.allTheArtists.length; x ++){ //going through every artist in the allTheArtistsArray
                    if($scope.similarBandsArray[i].name === $scope.allTheArtists[x].name){
                      counter ++;
                      if (counter > 0){
                        var toBeAddedToMutual = {
                          name: $scope.similarBandsArray[i],
                          count: counter
                        };
                      $scope.newMatchingArray.push(toBeAddedToMutual);
                      }
                    }
                    if($scope.soManyObjects && $scope.soManyObjects.amount > 0 ){
                        $scope.bigBoyArray.push($scope.soManyObjects.name + "and their count is" + ($scope.soManyObjects.amount + 1));
                      }
                  }
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < $scope.similarBandsArray.length; j ++){
                  $scope.allTheArtists.push($scope.similarBandsArray[j]);
                }
              }
            });
          };
```

Comment: As it is now you initialize the counter to 0 for every artist, so if you move the `var counter = 0` before the first `for` loop, at the end you'll have all the matches in the counter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more specific but when I place the counter outside both loops it simple marks each match in ascending order, when what I want is for the counter to keep track of how many times that "mutualArtists[i]" matched with the allTheArtists values (for example, the first value, if it matched with two of these values, could have a value of (2). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you find the first match, the `counter` becomes 1. And you create an object `toBeAddedToMutual` and insert it to an array. How can the count to be any other value?

Do you mean to move the second `if-block` out of the first `if-block`?

```
var counter = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < $scope.allTheArtists.length; x ++){
  if ($scope.similarBandsArray[i].name === $scope.allTheArtists[x].name){
    counter ++;
  }
  if (counter > 0) {
    var toBeAddedToMutual = {
      name: $scope.similarBandsArray[i],
      count: counter
    };
    $scope.newMatchingArray.push(toBeAddedToMutual);
  }
....
```

And as @FernandoPinheiro suggests, you might shorten your code with the lambda expressions.

```
angular.forEach($scope.similarBandsArray, function(band) {
  var matches = $scope.allTheArtists.filter(function(artist) {
    return band.name === artist.name;
  });
  if (matches.length) {
    $scope.newMatchingArray.push({
      name: band, // maybe you mean band.name
      count: matches.length
    });
  }
  ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more specific, but the problem is that when I place the counter outside of the for loop it gives each match an increment value (match1.count = 1, match2.count = 2, etc) when what I want is for the counts to count the amount of times that specific similarbands[i] matched a value in the allTheArtistsArray (for example, if the first similarBands[i] value matched with 2 allTheArtists values, it would have a count of 2, not 1. Thanks.

Comment: I maybe understand your problem now. You should find out the element in new array and update the counter there. I'd like to help you. Maybe you can update your question with a more clear inputs and outputs. E.g. give an array with couple of elements and describe how the result should look like.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this library: https://lodash.com/

It has every function that you will possibly need for your algorithm, like difference between arrays, filters, etc.

Comment: I do think lodash has what OP requires, but perhaps a specific example would be appropriate?

Comment: From my first look at the problem, his problem is declare the variable `counter` inside a loop. And you are right, lodash (or underscore) could actually make the code more compact.

Comment: I rather to give the man a fishing rod instead of feeding him for the day... there a plenty of examples in the lodash documentation....